# How to find flat file in SSIS with connection string variable

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which has a Flat File Connection Manager. The Connection Manager's Connection String is built dynamically using variables. This package has been running fine for years. Now I've had to add a new column to the flat file. My first problem is that the original Connection Manager didn't recognize the new column. I fixed that by creating a new Flat File Connection Manager, which does see the new column. However, when I try to run the package using the new Connection Manager, it tells me my file is not found. When I evaluate the expression for the Connection String, it's correct and the file does exist. Any idea what's going on here? For added fun, the Connection String includes a mapped drive, and Visual Studio 2017 (which I'm using) has an issue with seeing mapped drives. Could that be the issue?

The Connection Manager Connection String is

```
@[User::LocalPath] +@[User::LocalFileName]
```

`@[User::LocalPath]` is defined as

```
"H:\\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\Dayforce\\"
```

`@[User::LocalFileName]` is defined as

```
"SampleKLNF" 
+ (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE()) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2) 
+ ".csv" which today evaluates to SampleKLNF20211119.csv. My Connection
```

String thus evaluates today to `H:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Dayforce\SampleKLNF20211119*.csv`

Comment: Can you share more details ?

Comment: Happy to. What details would you like? I can tell you that the Connection Manager Connection String is @[User::LocalPath]+@[User::LocalFileName]. @[User::LocalPath] = "H:\\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\Dayforce\\" and @[User::LocalFileName] = "SampleKLNF" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2) + "*.csv" which today evaluates to SampleKLNF20211119*.csv. My Connection String thus evaluates today to H:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Dayforce\SampleKLNF20211119*.csv.

Comment: And the above file exists. There is just one.

Answer (score 0):

### Drive letters

Mapped drives, like your `H:` are unreliable in ETL as they are done at the user account level. My H: might be mounted at \server\share\billinkc whereas yours would look like \server\share\melanie  so even though we both have H:\data, we might not be talking about the same folder.

Additionally, it is unusual for a service account, the thing that will likely run the job on the SQL Server, to have a mapped drive.

Instead, I find it is less error prone to always reference network resource via a UNC path aka \server\share\folder\foo.csv instead of the mapped drive h:\folder\foo.csv  If you're unsure of how to figure out what the UNC is, from a command prompt (Start, cmd, `net share`)

Comment: That makes sense. So I changed the Connection Manager Connection String so that it evaluates to \\nyfil006\users\06717\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Dayforce\SampleKLNF20211119*.csv. Now SSIS is saying "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Error: 0xC020200E at Get Downloaded Data, Ceridian File [2]: Cannot open the datafile "\\nyfil006\users\06717\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Dayforce\SampleKLNF20211119*.csv"." And yet the Connection Manager sees all the files columns and I can open the file from File Explorer. ????

Comment: I thought perhaps the *.csv was an artifact of entering data. The flat file connection manager won't know how to open a file with that as it expects a literal, valid file path. The `*` is throwing things off.

Comment: No, this connection manager with an asterisk in the path has been working for years, so that's not the problem.